# How to get the k-th element in a jQuery set ... AS A JQUERY ELEMENT

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I encounter this situation often and I want to figure out a better way of going about it. I using the naming convention prefixing my jQuery elements with `$` so that I can distinguish them from DOM elements. For example, the following:

```
$pointers = $('#pointer-box div.pointer');
```

The problem with that is, if I want to get the 3rd in the result as a jQuery, I have to do

```
$($pointers[2])
```

which looks awkward. Unless there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**  jQuery method

```
$pointers = $('#pointer-box div.pointer');

var element=$pointers.eq(2);
```

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq()
>   method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that
>   set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the
>   set.

Comment: Never heard of .eq() despite having used jQuery for a long time. Kudos